# Can I add sign here filed to custom pdf and use it for embedded sign later

Tags: docusignapi

I have a PDF document. Can I modify it to include SignHere/InitialHere anchor text fields using DocuSign Account through UI and download the PDF in my server and use it later for embedded singing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think there are two options here:

1. You are asking about modifying your PDF. You can do that, but you would have to use some other software/API for this. This would allow you to use AnchorTags with the modified text that you chose.
2. You could add the SignHere/InitialHere tags via the API when you create the envelope. Here is some code example that can get you started:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ Inbar Gazit